# Confluence Issue with exporting

Tags: pdf, macros, export, confluence

We have created a custom user macro that creates a table of child pages, this table is also populated with information such as last updated, version, updated by etc.

When exporting the page the table is populated, however when you export the space the table is empty.

The code is below

```
## Macro title: Page Data
## Macro has a body: N
## Body processing: n/a
## Output: HTML
##
## Developed by: Brian Mitchell
## Date created: 06/27/2013
## @noparams

#set ($PageTitle = $content.displayTitle)
#set ($PageVersion = $content.version)
#set ($PageDate = $action.dateFormatter.formatGivenString("dd MMM yyyy",    $content.lastModificationDate))
#set ($PageAuthor = $content.lastModifierName)
#set ($pageListArray = [])
#set ($currentPage = $action.page)
#set ($spaceHome = $space.getHomePage())

#macro ( process $rp )
 #set ($pagelist = $rp.getSortedChildren() )  ## returns List<Page>
   #foreach( $child in $pagelist )
     #set($p = $pageListArray.add( $child ) )
       #if( $child.hasChildren() )
          #process ( $child )
    #end
 #end
#end

    #process ($currentPage)


    <h1> Confluence Page Versions </h1>
    <table class="confluenceTable">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th class="confluenceTh">Page Title</th>
    <th class="confluenceTh">Page Version</th>
     <th class="confluenceTh">Date</th>
     <th class="confluenceTh">Changed By</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>$PageTitle</td>
     <td><a href=http://confluence.mango.local/pages/viewpreviousversions.action?pageId=$content.getIdAsString()>$PageVersion</a></td>
      <td>$PageDate</td>
     <td>$PageAuthor</td>
     </tr>


      #foreach( $child in $pageListArray)   ## child is of type Page
        <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">$child.getTitle()</td>
        <td class="confluenceTd"><a href=http://confluence.mango.local/pages/viewpreviousversions.action?pageId=$child.getIdAsString()>$child.getVersion()</a> </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd">$action.dateFormatter.formatGivenString("dd MMM yyyy", $child.getLastModificationDate())</td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">$child.getLastModifierName()</td>
  </tr>
            #end

         </tbody>
        </table>
```

how ever when i edit the code to put the entire contents of the space in the array then the table is populated on export

so i replace 
         *#process ($currentPage)*
with 
         *#process ($spaceHome)*

so i think the problem is on space export the following command is not working 
*#set ($currentPage = $action.page)*

Does anyone have any ideas on what i could use instead?

Comment: Yeah the problem has to be that the $currentPage var isn't being defined for the macro until the page is viewed. How many pages are you using the macro on? It's not a great solution but you could create a unique macro for each page it will be used on and define the page more specifically

Comment: This is going to used across multiple spaces in confluence so i dont think this will be a suitable solution.

Comment: I can't think of any way to cause the $currentPage variable to be defined correctly without the page having been loaded. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `$action` Velocity variable refers to the current action being performed. In the situation when you are doing a space export, `$action` refers to the Export Space action rather than the Export Page action, and since the Export Space action does not have a `page` variable available from the action object, your `$action.page` does not return anything.

However, you are in luck: the Export Space feature does pass the context of the current page being exported, and you are already using it! `$content` refers to the ContentEntityObject being exported, which is actually the same thing that you were trying to get from `$action.page`.

To fix your example, simply adjust the call to the `#process` macro to use `$content`. The following works for me when exporting the entire space on Confluence 5.5:

```
## Macro title: Page Data
## Macro has a body: N
## Body processing: n/a
## Output: HTML
##
## Developed by: Brian Mitchell
## Date created: 06/27/2013
## @noparams

#set ($PageTitle = $content.displayTitle)
#set ($PageVersion = $content.version)
#set ($PageDate = $action.dateFormatter.formatGivenString("dd MMM yyyy",    $content.lastModificationDate))
#set ($PageAuthor = $content.lastModifierName)
#set ($pageListArray = [])
## #set ($currentPage = $action.page)
#set ($spaceHome = $space.getHomePage())

#macro ( process $rp )
 #set ($pagelist = $rp.getSortedChildren() )  ## returns List<Page>
   #foreach( $child in $pagelist )
     #set($p = $pageListArray.add( $child ) )
       #if( $child.hasChildren() )
          #process ( $child )
    #end
 #end
#end

    #process ($content)


    <h1> Confluence Page Versions </h1>
    <table class="confluenceTable">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th class="confluenceTh">Page Title</th>
    <th class="confluenceTh">Page Version</th>
     <th class="confluenceTh">Date</th>
     <th class="confluenceTh">Changed By</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>$PageTitle</td>
     <td><a href=http://confluence.mango.local/pages/viewpreviousversions.action?pageId=$content.getIdAsString()>$PageVersion</a></td>
      <td>$PageDate</td>
     <td>$PageAuthor</td>
     </tr>


      #foreach( $child in $pageListArray)   ## child is of type Page
        <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd">$child.getTitle()</td>
        <td class="confluenceTd"><a href=http://confluence.mango.local/pages/viewpreviousversions.action?pageId=$child.getIdAsString()>$child.getVersion()</a> </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd">$action.dateFormatter.formatGivenString("dd MMM yyyy", $child.getLastModificationDate())</td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">$child.getLastModifierName()</td>
  </tr>
            #end

         </tbody>
        </table>
```